# KSOAP2 java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot serialize

Tags: android, web-services, android-ksoap2

I am trying to use a method from a .net web service.

The code behind for the web service has a '/' at the end of the namespace

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://www.mynamespace.com/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
```

Here is the .net method call

```
POST /TelematicsWebService/Service.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://www.mynamespace.com/GetDevicesByBranch"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetDevicesByBranch xmlns="http://www.mynamespace.com/">
      <branchNumber>int</branchNumber>
    </GetDevicesByBranch>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Now the code calling the method looks like this

```
    @Override
    protected SoapObject doInBackground(Integer... branchNumber) {

        final String NAMESPACE = "http://www.mynamespace.com/";
        final String METHOD_NAME = "GetDevicesByBranch";
        final String SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE + METHOD_NAME;
        final String URL = "http://10.0.2.2/TelematicsWebService/Service.asmx";

        SoapObject response = null;

        try {
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

            PropertyInfo inputArgs = new PropertyInfo();
            inputArgs.setName("branchNumber");
            inputArgs.setValue(branchNumber);
            inputArgs.setType(Integer.class);
            request.addProperty(inputArgs);

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                    SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL,
                    25000);
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            response = null;
        }

        return response;
    }
```

The line towards the end, `androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);`, throws an exception: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot serialize: [Ljava.lang.Integer;@412e0cf0`

I can't find a solution to this issue, any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured it out...

This is inside an AsyncTask<>() if it wasn't already obvious with the Override doInBackground() method. The input parameter is a `Integer...` type.

```
protected SoapObject doInBackground(Integer... branchNumber)
```

I don't know what the ellipsis does exactly, but I know it makes the parameter an array.

I was passing an integer array into the request object rather than a specific array element.

changing from

```
request.addProperty("branchNumber", branchNumber);
```

to

```
request.addProperty("branchNumber", branchNumber[0]);
```

fixed the issue.

Thank you @Paul-Jan and @beginner! I appreciate your answers!

Comment: Completely missed that, thanks for sharing! I've deleted my answer, because aside from not helping, it was factually wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
PropertyInfo inputArgs = new PropertyInfo();
inputArgs.setName("branchNumber");
inputArgs.setValue(branchNumber);
inputArgs.setType(Integer.class);
request.addProperty(inputArgs);
```

try this:

```
request.addProperty("branchNumber", branchNumber);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have tried this. Unfortunately it yeilds the same result.

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to add a list of Object as a parameter of web service :

```
List<Object> vect = new Vector<Object>();
vect.add("Element1");
vect.add("Element2");
vect.add("Element3");

PropertyInfo tabProp =new PropertyInfo();
tabProp.setName("LIST_PARAM");          
tabProp.setValue(vect);

request.addProperty(tabProp );
```

Of course there is no need to note that the Async Task must implements the method :

```
protected String doInBackground(List<Object>... params){
....
....
}
```