# android webservice response "parse xml to pojo exception"

Tags: android, web-services, xml-parsing

I am trying to access soap webservices in android.

```
        AndroidHttpTransport httpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);
        ...
        ...
        String result = (String) httpTransport.responseDump;
```

I got the response **result** string as xml format given below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <soapenv:Body>
            <sampleResponse xmlns="http://impl.test.com">
                <sampleReturn>
                    <clientNameList>
                        <clientNameList>
                            <clientID>1</clientID>
                        </clientNameList>
                        <clientNameList>
                            <clientID>2</clientID>
                        </clientNameList>
                    </clientNameList>
                    <message>SUCCESS</message>
                </sampleReturn>
            </sampleResponse>
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Parsing this xml into Pojo using Simple XML Serialization(simple-xml-2.6.6.jar). **Ref:** [here](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/examples/examples.php)

```
        Persister persister = new Persister();
        UserResponse userResponse = persister.read(UserResponse.class, result);
```

Now I got the exception as

```
Element 'Body' does not have a match in class com.test.UserResponse at line 1
```

For more code information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066666/android-ksoap2-complex-typerequest-and-response)

How can I fix this?

UserResponse.java(POJO class)

```
public class UserResponse {

private String message = null;

private Client[] clientNameList = null;

public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

public void setClientNameList(Client[] clientNameList) {
        this.clientNameList = clientNameList;
    }

    public Client[] getClientNameList() {
        return clientNameList;
    }
}
```

and Client.java

```
public class Client {

private int clientID;

public void setClientID(int clientID) {
        this.clientID = clientID;
    }

    public int getClientID() {
        return clientID;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us the POJO classes that you have created.

Comment: I have added my POJO classes in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem in your response. You are getting `<clientNameList>` two times one after another so that might be causing you a problem in parsing the XML. So, better change your response accordingly.