# Android webservice ksoap2 - byte[] inside pojo Error

Tags: android, ksoap2

I am invoking java soap webservices from my android application using kvm serialization. my pojo classes and code is given below,

DataSet.java

```
public class DataSet implements KvmSerializable{

public String client = null;
public Photo[] images;
public String userId = null;

@Override
public Object getProperty(int arg0) {
    switch (arg0){
    case 0:
        return client;      
    case 1:
        return images;
    case 2:
        return userId;
     default:
         return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getPropertyCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 3;
}

@Override
public void getPropertyInfo(int index, Hashtable arg1, PropertyInfo info) {
    switch(index)
    {
    case 0:
        info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
        info.name = "client";
        break;        
    case 1:
        info.type = Photo.class;
        info.name = "images";
    case 2:
        info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
        info.name = "userId";
    default:
        break;
    }

}

@Override
public void setProperty(int index, Object value) {
    switch(index)
    {
    case 0:
        client = value.toString();
        break;
    case 1:
        images = (Photo[]) value;
        break;
    case 2:
        userId = value.toString();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

}
```

}

and Photo.java

```
public class Photo implements KvmSerializable{

public byte[] data;
public String name;

@Override
public Object getProperty(int arg0) {
    switch (arg0){
    case 0:
        return data;        
    case 1:
        return name;        
     default:
         return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getPropertyCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 2;
}

@Override
public void getPropertyInfo(int index, Hashtable arg1, PropertyInfo info) {
    switch(index)
    {
    case 0:
        info.type = byte[].class;
        info.name = "data";
        break;        
    case 1:
        info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
        info.name = "name";
    default:
        break;
    }

}

@Override
public void setProperty(int index, Object value) {
    switch(index)
    {
    case 0:
        data = (byte[])value;
        break;
    case 1:
        name = value.toString();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

}
```

In this I stored the images and name into the Photo.java POJO and then set into the DataSet POJO as,

```
public class Sample implements Runnable {
    ...
    ...
    Photo[] photoArr = new Photo[3];
    int count = 0;

public void run() {
  while (count < 3) {
    ....
    ....
    ....
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
    Photo photo = new Photo();
    photo.data = byteArray;
    photo.name = "img"+count;
    photoArr[count] = photo;
    count++;
 }
       if(count == 2)
         {
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            new MarshalBase64().register(envelope);   //serialization
            envelope.encodingStyle = SoapEnvelope.ENC;


            PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            dataSet.client = "1";
            dataSet.userId = "1";
            dataSet.images = photoArr;

            pi.setName("dataSet");
            pi.setValue(dataSet);
            pi.setType(dataSet.getClass());
            request.addProperty(pi);

            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request); 
            envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "dataSet", DataSet.class);
            envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "images", Photo.class);

            AndroidHttpTransport httpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);
            httpTransport.debug = true;                         
            httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

            SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
        Log.d("Result: ", result.toString());
         }
```

}

But I am getting the following error **Cannot serialize: [Lcom.common.Photo;@41221270**.

What is wrong im my code. I have searched about this issue. But I did't get correct answer.
 Can anyone help me to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the getPropertyInfo method of your Photo class, change the type for the data property from

`byte[].class`

to

`MarshalBase64.BYTE_ARRAY_CLASS`.

Change the value assignment in setProperty to

`data = Base64.decode(value.toString(), Base64.DEFAULT);`

Edit in response to your comment:

You also need to create a PhotoList class:

```
public class PhotoList extends Vector<Photo> implements
    KvmSerializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 12345L;  // you can let the IDE generate this

@Override
public Object getProperty(int index) {
    return this.get(index);
}

@Override
public int getPropertyCount() {
    return this.size();
}

@Override
public void setProperty(int index, Object value) {
    this.add((Photo) value);
}

@Override
public void getPropertyInfo(int index, Hashtable properties,
        PropertyInfo info) {
    info.name = "Photo";
    info.type = Photo.class;
}
}
```

Change your DataSet class implementation so images is of type PhotoList and initialize it.  Also change the types in your getPropertyInfo/setProperty methods.

```
PhotoList images = new PhotoList();
...
info.type = PhotoList.class;
...
images = (PhotoList)value;
```

You will also need to add the PhotoList mapping to your SOAP envelope.

Comment: In setProperty "this.add((Photo) value);" shows some error. When I click quickfix this will changed to "this.add((PhotoList) value);"

Comment: Sorry, typo - the class should extend Vector<Photo> not Vector<PhotoList>.

Comment: thanks Willy.I have changed it. Now I am getting error in Sample.java file "dataSet.images = photoArr;". Because I declared photoArr is type of "Photo[]". If I change this type to "PhotoList[]" I also need to change "photo" object's type to "PhotoList". If I change this 'll get error on "photo.data" and "photo.name".

Comment: photoArr should be of type PhotoList (a List<Photo>), not PhotoList[] (an array of List<Photo>s).  (For clarity, you should probably also change the name to photoList.)  To add an item to the list, use photoList.Add(photo)

Comment: I have created PhotoList and set values of photo to PhotoList using photoList.Add(photo); dataSet.images = photoList; envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "images", photoList.getClass()); . Now I am getting the error "SoapFault - faultcode: 'soapenv:Server.userException' faultstring: 'org.xml.sax.SAXException: SimpleDeserializer encountered a child element, which is NOT expected, in something it was trying to deserialize.' faultactor: 'null' detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@413032f8".

Comment: It sounds like your web service is returning something unexpected, can you post the httpTransport.responseDump?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Body><soapenv:Fault><faultcode>soapenv:Server.userException</faultcode><faultstring>org.xml.sax.SAXException:SimpleDeserializer encountered a child element,which is NOT expected, in something it was trying to deserialize</faultstring><detail><ns1:hostname xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">admin-PC</ns1:hostname></detail></soapenv:Fault></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>

Comment: If that's the response dump then this is an issue with your web service, not the client.  Check the requestDump in your client to make sure you're sending the request you want, but this appears to be a different issue.